# SDL2 tilemap - too slow

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-2

I'm using SDL2 to write a game that displays a tilemap at every frame, but the performance is too slow. I wrote a little program to isolate the problem. Consider that "temp.bmp" is a 16x16 image.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "SDL2/SDL.h"
#include "SDL2/SDL_timer.h"
#include "SDL2/SDL_image.h"

int main()
{
    SDL_Window* win;
    SDL_Renderer* ren;
    int x, y;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(800, 600, 0, &win, &ren);
    SDL_Surface* sf = IMG_Load("temp.bmp");
    SDL_Texture* tx = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(ren, sf);

    for(;;) {
        Uint32 t = SDL_GetTicks();
        for(x=0; x<800; x+=16) {
            for(y=0; y<600; y+=16) {
                SDL_Rect src = { 0, 0, 16, 16 };
                SDL_Rect dst = { x, y, 16, 16 };
                SDL_RenderCopy(ren, tx, &src, &dst);
            }
        }
        SDL_RenderPresent(ren);
        printf("%ld ms\n", SDL_GetTicks() - t);
    }
}
```

Running the program, I see that it takes about 16ms to render a frame. This is exactly 60 FPS (1000/60), which leaves no room for game logic. Also, I'm running it in a pretty fast computer.

I'm pretty sure I'm using the wrong strategy, but I'm not sure what be the right one. Maybe creating a big texture and updating it less often would be the way to go, but I couldn't find any documentation on how to copy one texture over another.

So, how can I improve the tilemap performance?

Comment: could you add a performance mesure before `SDL_RenderPresent`to know if you loose your time there of before.

Comment: I don't know SDL2, but maybe rendering is being limited by vsync? Have you tried running in fullscreen mode?

Comment: @dzada Most of the time is spent on SDL_RenderPresent. About 2 ms before, and 14 ms after.

Comment: @user694733 I tested with full screen, but I got the same result. Also, SDL2 now has a flag that indicates whether VSYNC is being used or not: http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateRenderer

Comment: As far as I know, these flags can be overridden by the video driver. Maybe `SDL_GetRendererInfo` helps you.

Comment: Do you know if you video card is used or only your CPU (does it use opengl behind ?)

Comment: @user694733 By using SDL_GetRendererInfo, I get that I'm using hardware acceleration (SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED is set and SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE is not set).

Comment: @dzada By using SDL_GetRendererInfo, I get that I'm not being blocked by VSYNC (SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC is not set).

Comment: Best way of testing if VSYNC is locked on by either the code, GFX card/drivers or something else is to just draw a single tile. You should get well over 100+ fps for that. If it stays at 60 then you can be pretty sure VSYNC is on.

Answer (score 2):

On [this](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateRenderer) page it mentions that SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC flag means you are synced to refresh rate.
try this

```
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
```

Comment: By using SDL_GetRendererInfo, I get that I'm using hardware acceleration (SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED is set and SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE is not set). I also get that I'm not being blocked by VSYNC (SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC is not set).

Comment: Ok sorry I thought it was set.

Answer (score 1):

On my system with vsync I have plenty of extra time (~15ms) before `SDL_RenderPresent()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_timer.h>

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    SDL_Window* win;
    SDL_Renderer* ren;
    int x, y;

    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO );

    win = SDL_CreateWindow
        ( 
        "Window", 
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 
        800, 600, 
        0 
        );

    ren = SDL_CreateRenderer
        ( 
        win, 
        -1,
        SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC
        );

    for(;;) 
    {
        Uint32 t = SDL_GetTicks();
        for(x=0; x<800; x+=16) 
        {
            for(y=0; y<600; y+=16) 
            {
                SDL_Rect dst = { x, y, 16, 16 };
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( ren, rand()%255, rand()%255, rand()%255, 255 );
                SDL_RenderFillRect( ren, &dst );
            }
        }

        // adjust this up/down to figure out how much extra time you have
        // stop when you start seeing frame times exceeding ~16ms
        SDL_Delay( 15 );

        SDL_RenderPresent(ren);
        printf("%ld ms\n", SDL_GetTicks() - t);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can render to a big texture first by using [SDL_SetRenderTarget](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetRenderTarget). That texture than then be drawn only once per frame.

I.e. something like:

```
Uint32 fmt;
SDL_QueryTexture(tx, &fmt, NULL, NULL, NULL);
SDL_Texture* tm = SDL_CreateTexture(ren, fmt, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET, 800, 600);
SDL_SetRenderTarget(ren, tm);
// Your draw loop here
SDL_SetRenderTarget(ren, NULL);
// Real draw loop only needs to RenderCopy tm
```

Answer (score 0):

It's vertical sync forced by your graphics driver (opengl backend). It is user-controlled, and is intended to be unchangeable by applications themselves.